# Heisenberg group as a suspension

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

I'm working on Heisenberg group and I want to understand the suspension viewpoint. Let me be more precise. Let us denote by $\mathbb{H}^3(A)$ the set of matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & x& z \\ 0 &1 & y\\ 0 &0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with $A$ a ring. 
It is easy to show that is a group for the natural product. Now we put

\begin{equation}
G = \mathbb{H}^3(\mathbb{R}) \backslash \mathbb{H}^3(\mathbb{Z}) 
\end{equation}

A normal subgroup of $G$ is the set of class :

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0& z \\ 0 &1 & y\\ 0 &0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
(which is isomorphic to the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$)

The quotient is then an other Lie group. Indeed it is a also a suspension of the torus by the following linear map :

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1  \\ 0 &1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

If one have an hint of proof that the both definition give us the same topological object, as a manifold I will be very gratefull (one by suspension and the other by the quotient that I've defined above).

Comment: Say the group's name.

Comment: @GitGud You're goddamn right